# No Such Element ERROR while trying to extract the table from a website

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to extract the table from the website https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Sharehold_Searchnew.aspx?expandable=3

```
shell('docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome')
Sys.sleep(2)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
Sys.sleep(2)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" , port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
Sys.sleep(3)
remDr$open()
remDr$setTimeout(type = "script", milliseconds = 30000000000)
remDr$navigate("https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Sharehold_Searchnew.aspx?expandable=3")
webelemtemp<-remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_gvData']/tbody/tr[27]/td/table/tbody")
count<-1
```

Getting an error
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
Further Details: run errorDetails method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the table we can use,

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

remDr$navigate("https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Sharehold_Searchnew.aspx?expandable=3")

remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.mGrid') %>% 
  html_table()
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `Security Code` `Security Name`         Industry                     `For Quarter Ending` XBRL 
            <int> <chr>                   <chr>                        <chr>                <lgl>
1          509055 VISAKA INDUSTRIES LTD.  Cement & Cement Products     09 Feb 2022          NA   
2          532687 REPRO INDIA LTD.        Comm.Printing/Stationery     December 2021        NA   
3          538734 Ceinsys Tech Ltd        IT Consulting & Software     09 Feb 2022          NA   
4          532695 CELEBRITY FASHIONS LTD. Other Apparels & Accessories 27 Jan 2022          NA
```

But a faster approach would be using `rvest`

```
url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.mGrid') %>% 
  html_table()
```